# Set margin of actionLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

The following is the button of my actionLayout. Basically, my actionBar has MenuItems and one of the items has the following button as actionLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fruit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Apple" />
```

My problem is the height of the button keeps filling the parent. I want to set margins but nothing is working. Does anyone know a simple way to set the margins?

Comment: Have You tried to put Button inside FrameLayout?

Comment: Do you mind showing how that would look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the button in `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/fruit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="#999999"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Apple" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And it would look like the following:

[image: device action bar]

Comment: This works, but a click on the margin space will trigger the action, too.